# Screen coordinates in R

Tags: r, graphics

I would like to draw two perpendicular lines on the current device. They should both have the same apparent length on the device, irrespective of aspect ratio of the output and the device size.

Is this at all doable? In principle this is the problem of drawing a perfect circle on the screen.

Comment: If you want to draw a perfect circle, use `symbols(x,y,circle=r,add=TRUE,inches=TRUE)` or similar

Comment: I know, but I want my perpendicular lines :-)

Comment: `symbols` with very thin rectangles? No, I think grid is the answer, seems you can draw in fixed device coords.

Comment: OK, so the problem is actually more complicated, but knowing how to draw these lines is its solution. pin from par() seems at the moment the easiest solution, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could retrieve the current graphics window coordinates.  Thanks to Josh O'Brian for providing me with this code a while back.  First you create a window (or plot something), then run this line:

```
 myasp <- with(par(),(pin[2]/pin[1])/(diff(usr[3:4])/diff(usr[1:2])))
```

Then use that aspect information to adjust the lengths of the lines you're going to plot.

Comment: Great, this is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

there are several ways, i find it easier in grid graphics

```
library(grid)

grid.circle()
vp <- viewport(width=unit(0.5, "snpc"), height=unit(0.5, "snpc"))
grid.rect(vp=vp, gp=gpar(lty=2))
grid.segments(x0=c(0,0), x1=c(1,1), 
              y0=c(0,1), y1=c(1,0), 
              default.units="npc", vp=vp)
```

Comment: Apart from `symbols`, I'm not sure its possible to plot something tied to anything other than "user" (ie plot axis) coordinates with the base graphics (points, lines) routines. You can convert with `grconvertX` and `grconvertY` but you are still plotting with user coords, so resizing the plot screws your aspect ratio. So +1 for grid!

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the `grconvertX` and `grconvertY` functions.  Using these you can specify coordinates in inches or other units and from that compute the user coordinates for drawing your line.